# Checking to see if there is more data to read from a file descriptor using Python's select module

Tags: python, linux, select, subprocess

I have a program that creates a subprocess within a thread, so that the thread can be constantly checking for specific output conditions (from either stdout or stderr), and call the appropriate callbacks, while the rest of the program continues. Here is a pared-down version of that code:

```
import select
import subprocess
import threading

def run_task():
    command = ['python', 'a-script-that-outputs-lines.py']
    proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
    while True:

        ready, _, _ = select.select((proc.stdout, proc.stderr), (), (), .1)

        if proc.stdout in ready:
            next_line_to_process = proc.stdout.readline()
            # process the output

        if proc.stderr in ready:
            next_line_to_process = proc.stderr.readline()
            # process the output

        if not ready and proc.poll() is not None:
            break

thread = threading.Thread(target = run_task)
thread.run()
```

It works reasonably well, but I would like the thread to exit once two conditions are met: the running child process has finished, and all of the data in stdout and stderr has been processed.

The difficulty I have is that if my last condition is as it is above (`if not ready and proc.poll() is not None`), then the thread never exits, because once stdout and stderr's file descriptors are marked as ready, they never become unready (even after all of the data has been read from them, and `read()` would hang or `readline()` would return an empty string).

If I change that condition to just `if proc.poll() is not None`, then the loop exists when the program exits, and I can't guarantee that it's seen all of the data that needs to be processed.

Is this just the wrong approach, or is there a way to reliably determine when you've read all of the data that will ever be written to a file descriptor? Or is this an issue specific to trying to read from the stderr/stdout of a subprocess?

I have been trying this on Python 2.5 (running on OS X) and also tried `select.poll()` and `select.epoll()`-based variants on Python 2.6 (running on Debian with a 2.6 kernel).

Comment: The solution I'm currently running with is to test if `next_line_to_process` is empty (right after calling `readline()`), and if it is empty and the output of `proc.poll()` is None, then I remove the file descriptor from the ready list and continue on to the next one (or see if it's time to exit). But I'd be interested to know if there is any other solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`select` module is appropriate if you want to find out whether you can read from a pipe without blocking.

To make sure that you've read all data, use a simpler condition `if proc.poll() is not None: break` and call `rest = [pipe.read() for pipe in [p.stdout, p.stderr]]` after the loop.

It is unlikely that a subprocess closes its stdout/stderr before its shutdown therefore you could skip the logic that handles EOF for simplicity.

---

Don't call `Thread.run()` directly, use `Thread.start()` instead. You probably don't need the separate thread here at all.

Don't call `p.stdout.readline()` after the `select()`, it may block, use `os.read(p.stdout.fileno(), limit)` instead. Empty bytestring indicates EOF for the corresponding pipe.

---

As an alternative or in addition to you could make the pipes non-blocking using `fcntl` module:

```
import os
from fcntl import fcntl, F_GETFL, F_SETFL

def make_nonblocking(fd):
    return fcntl(fd, F_SETFL, fcntl(fd, F_GETFL) | os.O_NONBLOCK)
```

and handle io/os errors while reading.

Comment: Thanks, that's really helpful. I did not know about the `fcntl` module.

Comment: subprocess does close its file descriptors before shutdown somtimes.

Comment: @sivann  it is very unlikely that a process closes its stdout in the middle of execution (i.e., it is possible but I don't know any real world examples).

Answer (score 2):

My eventual solution, as I mentioned above, was the following, in case this is helpful to anyone. I think it is the right approach, since I'm now 97.2% sure you can't do this with just `select()`/`poll()` and `read()`:

```
import select
import subprocess
import threading

def run_task():
    command = ['python', 'a-script-that-outputs-lines.py']
    proc = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
    while True:

        ready, _, _ = select.select((proc.stdout, proc.stderr), (), (), .1)

        if proc.stdout in ready:
            next_line_to_process = proc.stdout.readline()
            if next_line_to_process:
                # process the output
            elif proc.returncode is not None:
                # The program has exited, and we have read everything written to stdout
                ready = filter(lambda x: x is not proc.stdout, ready)

        if proc.stderr in ready:
            next_line_to_process = proc.stderr.readline()
            if next_line_to_process:
                # process the output
            elif proc.returncode is not None:
                # The program has exited, and we have read everything written to stderr
                ready = filter(lambda x: x is not proc.stderr, ready)

        if proc.poll() is not None and not ready:
            break

thread = threading.Thread(target = run_task)
thread.run()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a raw `os.read(fd, size)` on the pipe's file descriptor instead of using `readline()`. This is a non-blocking operation which can also detect EOF (in that case it returns an empty string or byte object). You'd have to implement the line splitting and buffering yourself. Use something like this:

```
class NonblockingReader():
  def __init__(self, pipe):
    self.fd = pipe.fileno()
    self.buffer = ""

  def readlines(self):
    data = os.read(self.fd, 2048)
    if not data:
      return None

    self.buffer += data
    if os.linesep in self.buffer:
      lines = self.buffer.split(os.linesep)
      self.buffer = lines[-1]
      return lines[:-1]
    else:
      return []
```

Comment: In this case, blocking/non-blocking behaviour isn't a huge deal, because I don't have two threads reading from the same file descriptor. However, `os.read()` returns an empty string, not None, when it reaches the end of the file: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.read

Comment: That's right, it's empty string in 2.x. But I think it should be None in newer 3.x versions.

Comment: I don't think so. In Python 3 it appears to be an empty `bytes` object: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/os.html#os.read