# Python Socket Chat: Client recv() hanging

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I have a small problem with a chat program I am trying to build:
There are 2 clients and a server, a client sends out a message and the server receives it, and broadcasts it to everyone (usually both clients, but there can be more). The problem is, that when A client sends data to the other client (through the server), the receiving client has to send something himself in order to see the message.

This is my server.py:

```
import socket
from thread import start_new_thread
import threading


def thread(c,clients, c_lock,buf=1024,):
    c.send("You are connected! \n")
    while True:
        try:
            data = c.recv(buf)
            print data
            if not data:
                break
            broadcast(clients,c_lock,data)
        except socket.error as e:
            exit(0)
    c.close()

def broadcast(clients,c_lock,data):
    with c_lock:
        for c in clients:
            c.sendall("- " + data)

def main():
    host = ''
    port = 10000
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    clients = set()
    clients_lock = threading.Lock()
    s.bind((host, port))
    s.listen(5)
    print "%s listening on %s" % (host, str(port))
    while True:
            c, addr = s.accept()
            print "got connection from ", addr
            with clients_lock:
                clients.add(c)
            start_new_thread(thread, (c, clients, clients_lock, ))
    s.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

And client.py:

```
import socket
import time
from sys import exit

def main():
    host = socket.gethostname()
    port = 10000
    name = str(raw_input("Enter your name: "))


    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        s.connect(('192.168.1.12', port))
    except Exception as e:
        print 'Connection not working... %s' % (e)
        exit()

    print s.recv(1024)  # greeting msg
    print "Send q to stop the connection \n"
    out = ''
    while out != 'q':
        out = str(raw_input('->'))
        recv =  s.recv(1024)
        s.send(name + ": " + out)
        time.sleep(0.1)
        print recv
    s.close()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Thanks for your help :)
(And please forgive me for the mess :/)

Comment: Your clients are spending most of their time in `raw_input()`, and cannot possibly receive anything.  If you did the input/send and the receive in separate threads, things would work - but the result would be a jumbled mess on the screen if a message arrives while the user is typing.  You really need either a GUI, or a text interface like `curses`, so that the user input and the incoming messages are in separate areas of the screen, that cannot interfere with each other.

Comment: alright so what you tell me is that I should wait for a respond from the other client?

Comment: @LiorDahan No, he's saying you should use a interface that can handle input while displaying output. curses or a gui. Or you can read off `sys.stdin` one character at a time when data is available, print the recieved data and reprint the current user input state. But realistically, use [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html) if you're on linux. If you're on windows just go for tkinter/wxPython/qt/gtk+ or any other framework of [your poison](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/gui.html). Or just use threads and live with the scrambled input/output for now.

Answer (score 3):

You have two issues.

`recv()` is a blocking call.
`raw_input()` / `input()` are also a blocking call.

Meaning the client will "hang" on both of these calls (`recv()` being an exception **if** there is data in the pipe, then it won't block).

To get around this, as in your example. Either you can use `threading` as you've done in your server to have a class/instance that is souly responsible for retrieving data from the socket and one to read user input. Or on Linux you can use `select.select` or `select.epoll` to poll the socket if data is in the pipe and only then, call `recv()`. And for the input you're still better off using `select/epoll` on `sys.stdin` or use threading.

But `recv()` will always be a blocking call in Python (and many other languages) if there is no data available to read. And so will `raw_input()` / `input()`.

To use [epoll](https://docs.python.org/2/library/select.html#select.epoll), here's a short example:

```
from select import epoll, EPOLLIN
import sys

polly = epoll()
polly.register(s.fileno(), EPOLLIN)
polly.register(sys.stdin.fileno(), EPOLLIN)

for fid, eid in polly.poll(1):
    # s is your socket, s.fileno() on linux is the file number that socket has been assigned to.
    # And epoll returns a list of all filenumbers that has data waiting.
    # So we can check if the fid from epoll == the sockets filenumber.
    if fid == s.fileno(): 
        data = s.recv(8192)
    # of if it's sys.stdin's filenumber
    # (stdin is user input, this is where raw_input normally gets its data from)
    elif fid == sys.stdin.fileno():
        user_input = sys.stdin.readline()
        print('User wrote:', user_input)
```

Or if you want to use threading:

```
from threading import Thread, enumerate as t_enum
class userInput(Thread):
    def __init__(self, socket, username):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.socket = socket
        self.username = username
        self.start()

    def run(self):
        mainThread = None
        for thread in t_enum():
            if thread.name == 'MainThread':
                mainThread = thread
                break

        while mainThread and mainThread.isAlive():
            out = raw_input('->') # str() is redundant, it's type(str) already.
            self.socket.send(self.username + ": " + out)
```

And a little further down your code:

```
name = str(raw_input("Enter your name: "))

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:
    s.connect(('192.168.1.12', port))
except Exception as e:
    print 'Connection not working... %s' % (e)
    exit()

userInput(s, name)
```

Note that this isn't proper thread handling. But it's a minimal example that will show you the general gist of how to go about the problem.

as a last tipe, [fcntl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23702542/929999) is also a good option.

### Further programming for the future tips

use `print(...)` instead of `print ...`
use `'Connection not working... {}'.format(e)` instead of `'Connection not working... %s' % (e)`
And overall, try to use Python3 instead of Python2. Python2 should really only be used if you have a old environment filled with legacy stuff (read: debian, old developed applications etc).